# How to navigate to a nested screen by dispatching an action in React Navigation 5.x?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm migrating an app from 4.x to 5.x and i'm new to react-navigation.
I'm looking for a way to dispatch an action to navigate inside a nested screen.

The [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) explain how to navigate to a nested screen like this

```
navigation.navigate('home', { screen: 'secondList'})
```

But i want to do the same with `navigation.dispatch()`

I was able to make a reset like this

```
   navigation.dispatch(
      CommonActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [
          {
            name: 'home',
            state: {
              routes: [
                {
                  name: 'secondList',
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      })
    );
```

but I'm not sure that you have to do the same for a simple navigation.

My screens configuration is quite simple

```
    // Root navigator
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName={'intro'}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="intro" component={IntroScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="home" component={HomeNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

   // Home navigator
    <Stack.Navigator
      headerMode={'screen'}
      initialRouteName={'firstList'}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name={'firstList'} component={firstScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'secondList'} component={secondScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'thirdList'} component={thirdScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions), you can reset the route using the following:

```
      navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'home',
              params: { screen: 'secondList', params: {exampleParam: 'example'} },
            },
          ],
        })
      );
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to do a reset of the state.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this solution.

```
navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({ name: home, params: { screen: secondList } }))
```

As the documentation mentions it `navigation.navigate()` is the same as doing `navigation.dispatch(CommonAction.navigate())`

Comment: Yeah, you are right that both are same according to the documentation but here is a little bit difference that is more important to know
**_"It's important to highlight that dispatching a navigation action doesn't throw any error when the action is unhandled (similar to when you dispatch an action that isn't handled by a reducer in redux and nothing happens)."_** - [Read more](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/)